# Warn message in ActiveMQ Artemis console

Tags: jetty, activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.28.0, and I suddenly received this warning message:

```
2023-09-19 09:49:09,160 WARN  [org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel] /console/jolokia/
java.lang.IllegalStateException: null
```

[image]

Comment: I am using 2.28 artemis active mq and broker version, Didn't do any particular activities.
Any specific reason for getting that error

Comment: While accessing or checking something in the artemis web console, Suddenly getting the WARN in the cmd console like this "2023-09-20 10:55:09,689 WARN "[org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel] /console/jolokia/ java.lang.IllegalStateException: null "   It will cause any issue in the production server ?

Comment: No Functional Impact !

Comment: While receiving the Warn message our application facing slowness, I am not sure how to get rid of the jetty warn msg even though i have updated the broker version currently broker running on 2.30 !

Comment: The "application slowness" may be related and it may not. Without more details its impossible to say. You asked this question a week ago and this is the first time you've mentioned anything about "application slowness." There's nothing the broker can do about the warning message. It's coming directly from the embedded web server (i.e. Jetty).

Answer (score 0):

The WARN message is being logged by Jetty (i.e. the embedded web server) which is not part of the ActiveMQ Artemis code-base. Looking at [the relevant source code from Jetty](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-10.0.15/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/Session.java#L912) indicates that the exception is due to an attempt to invalidate a web session that is already invalid. There should be no functional impact here.

Comment: Thank you, yes i am investigation on Jetty server. Broker is working fine

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help others who have same question in the future. Thanks!